# Малая точность формата float

Tags: float, c++

Имеется следующий код:

```
namespace type{
    float a0 = 0.0f;
    float a1 = 0.1f;

    // ...

    float a7 = 0.7f;

    //...
};
```

В дальнейшем я использую `ai` для извлечения их дробной части и использую эту часть как индекс элемента массива.

Но вот возникла такая штука: `a7` оказалось равным `0.699999` после такой операции `a7 = 0.7;`. Почему? Почему так не точно? Я попробовал вывести значение на экран: оно равно `0.7`.  В режиме отладки выяснил, что там все же не `0.7`, а `0.69999`. Значения переменных `аi` должны быть `float`, так как они фигурирует в коде именно в таком виде.

Как быть?

Comment: @Alerr, думаю Вам лучше пересмотреть структуры данных. 

Использование дробной части числа с плавающей точкой в качестве индекса - это не самая хорошая идея (поверьте, она чревата кучей ошибок).

--

Опишите всю задачу, тогда можно подумать, как надо делать.

Comment: @Alerr - почитайте к примеру хотя бы это: [Что нужно знать про арифметику с плавающей запятой](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/) и запомните как прописную истину. И больше не используйте вещественные числа для точных расчетов.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил написать клас, в котором будет отдельно содержатся целая часть и дробная: число a.bc представить в класе тремя переменными `int a, b, c;` и реальзовать все необходимые операции. Таким образом можно получить необходимую точность.

Answer (score 2):

*Из комментария пользователя [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim):*

Почитайте, к примеру, хотя бы это: «[Что нужно знать про арифметику с плавающей запятой](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/)» и запомните как прописную истину. И больше не используйте вещественные числа для точных расчетов.