# Как зафиксировать точность переменной float?

Tags: c, типы-данных, float

Итак, нужно зафиксировать определенную точность переменных типа float, т.е., чтобы в них записывать числа с точностью до, например, 2 знаков после запятой. К примеру, `float a = 1.125;` должно сохранить значение 1.12. Как это можно сделать? Важно!!! Не вывести! А чтобы переменная `а` сохранила число с 2-мя знаками после запятой.
Спасибо!

Comment: Во-первых, числа и так точно не хранятся, а уж обрезанные - и подавно, и будет ваше обрезание чем-то вроде 1.1199534673. А во-вторых, что-то у меня подозрение, что это вопрос не о том, как забить гвоздь, а как держать микроскоп при его забивании... В чем именно состоит ваша сверхзадача?

Comment: просто нужна фиксированная точность после запятой - вот и все

Comment: Просто работайте с нормальной, а потом округляйте результат.

Comment: Вообще-то и я об этом. Просто хочу выяснить более эффективный способ округления, чем умножать на 100, отбрасывать лишние нули, а потом снова делить на 100

Comment: Вам нужно именно до 10^-2, или количество знаков? Т.е. 3.1415->3.14 понятно, но что вы хотите от 31415.925358 и от 0.0000314159?

Comment: 31415.92 и 0 соответственно

Comment: Более эффективного способа, откровенно говоря, не вижу. только я бы умножал на 100, прибавлял 0.5, затем `floor` + деление. Ну, конечно, с учетом знака числа.

Comment: Точность флоат в принципе не возможно зафиксировать, потому что flot не позволяет хранить точное значение. Т.е. может так оказаться, что 0.567 он хранить в принципе не способен, а хранит скажем 0.56700001  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/249465/194569  так что лучше округлять уже в самом конце, когда все расчеты уже произведены

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Важно!!! Не вывести! А чтобы переменная `а` сохранила число с 2-мя знаками после запятой.

`float` тип представляет числа с *плавающей* точкой (*float*ing point). Если вы хотите числа с *фиксированной* точкой (ровно 2 цифры после запятой), то другой тип используйте. К примеру, вместо дробных рублей, в целых копейках храните данные — это гарантирует, что всегда только две цифры после запятой хранятся (если в рублях считать).

Как обрабатывать округление, переполнение для арифметики на копейках, зависит от задачи.

Comment: У меня тоже возникло подозрение, что речь идёт об операциях с денежными значениями. Ни в коем случае НЕ используйте плавающую арифметику в денежных расчётах. jfs подсказывает тоже не совсем корректный путь. На самом деле надо завести структуру, состоящую из целого поля рублей и целого поля копеек. Ещё в советских ГОСТ-ах были описаны правила проведения экономических вычислений с такой структурой. Если НЕ следовать этому ГОСТ, то в ночь на 31 декабря выяснится, что баланс не бъётся на одну копейку и вся бухгалтерия начнёт топтать Вас (с наслаждением) острыми шпильками. :-)

Comment: @Sergey рубли и копейки это просто величины, которые в 100 раз отличаются и  которые знакомы людям. Это пример как арифметика на дробях (рублях) сводится к целой арифметике (на копейках). Это приём, чтобы объяснение простое и краткое было. Я не имел в виду, что задача буквально к деньгам относится (там вероятно законодательно ограничения на хранение итд присутствуют).