# Умножения double на double

Tags: c

Всем доброго времени суток. Встретил такую проблему при умножении Double на Double: при умножении 2 чисел я получаю результат с точность до комы. 
Пример кода

```
x = data->perp_wall_dist * data->ray_dir_y;
printf("perp_wall == %f ,  ray_dir = %f, dou*dou == %f\n", data->perp_wall_dist, data->ray_dir_y, data->perp_wall_dist * data->ray_dir_y);
```

Пример нескольких результатов

1. perp_wall == 3.078403 ,  ray_dir = 0.649688, perp_wall*ray_dir == 2.000000
2. perp_wall == 3.068661 ,  ray_dir = 0.651750, perp_wall*ray_dir == 2.000000
3. perp_wall == 3.058981 ,  ray_dir = 0.653813, perp_wall*ray_dir == 2.000000

и т.д

Почему результат неточный, точность вычислений критически важна и как можно устранить эту проблему?

Comment: Что за "точность до комы"? `printf` с `%f` по умолчанию округляет до 6 знаков после точки, попробуйте точность побольше поставить.

Comment: Рано или поздно все программисты на это натыкаются. Если нужна супер-точность, нужно будет реализовать такую математику самому. А для начала почитать о все этом https://habr.com/post/112953/  А если кратко, скорее всего Вам такая точность и не нужна.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Малая точность формата float](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249465/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-float)

Answer (score 2):

Вы вроде бы работаете с `double`, но выводите значения как `float`. Используйте правильные спецификаторы - [сравните вывод в двух строках](https://ideone.com/NAIjTB) сами:

```
double perp_wall_dist[3] = {3.078403, 3.068661, 3.058981 };
double ray_dir_y[3]      = {0.649688, 0.651750, 0.653813 };

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    printf("perp_wall == %f ,  ray_dir = %f, dou*dou == %f\n",
           perp_wall_dist[i], ray_dir_y[i], perp_wall_dist[i] * ray_dir_y[i]);
    printf("perp_wall == %.12lf ,  ray_dir = %.12f, dou*dou == %.12f\n\n",
           perp_wall_dist[i], ray_dir_y[i], perp_wall_dist[i] * ray_dir_y[i]);
}
```

Comment: Спецификаторы `%f` и `%lf` в `printf` полностью эквивалентны. То есть `printf` не предоставляет возможности "выводить как `float`". А вот указание precision - это другое дело.